# Enable users of project to configure their own CMake prefix path

Tags: github, cmake

Consider a situation where people work together on the same code base; C++ with CMake. Code base depends on a library, that must be installed separately.

Each user may have the library in a different location. A user may invoke CMake like this:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/for/that/user .
```

However, this is not very easy in all circumstances (e.g. windows and visual studio), and requires retyping. So instead, we have

```bash
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/path/for/user")
```

In the CMakeLists.txt. This works, but requires people to constantly change that path after pulling a branch, which is annoying and easily forgotten. Is it possible to configure in a way that pulling new branches does not override this path, once set on a specific machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have each of your users create their own [CMakeUserPresets.json](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) file, and set it in the `cacheVariables` field of a `configurePresets` entry.

```json
{
  "version": , // pick one
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": , // pick one
    "minor": , // pick one
    "patch":   // pick one
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "starball",
      "displayName": "Starball's config",
      "description": "Starball's private configuration preset",
      "generator": "...",
      "binaryDir": "...",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "..."
      },
      "environment": {}
    }
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Make sure to put `CMakeUserPresets.json` in your .gitignore file (or whatever else you have to do for your specific VCS so that the user preset file isn't tracked in the VCS).